# Combining two XPaths with condition

Tags: xpath, automation

I'm using the "Auto click" chrome extension to automate a task.
With this extension I'm able to select a specific XPath that is going to be clicked.
I would need it to only click if the xpath next to it contains a specific text.

So imagine two buttons next to each other:

```
Button 1 xpath: //*[@id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_List1_View1_ctl03_Label4”]

Button 2 xpath: //*[@id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_List1_View1_ctl03_Button1”]
```

Button 1 contains the text "noclick"

Now I need to combine these two xpaths, so if Button 1 contains the text "noclick" then click Button 2

Am I on the right path with this? ->

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_List1_View1_ctl03_Label4” and span[contains(text(),’noclick’)]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If the 1st expresision returns false (does not returns anything), Xpath will check the 2nd'

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_List1_View1_ctl03_Label4”][not(contains(., "noclick")] || 
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_List1_View1_ctl03_Button1”]
```